# URL and Port redirect on IIS

Tags: iis, redirect

I'm struggling with an issue in IIS 8.5 which is about redirection and rewriting, but couldn't get a solution yet

we have an application driven Webpage running on IIS, but is not manageable.
This application can attached by browser using 
http:// 10.172.100.242:81/appname/object?parameter 
which is not really customer friendly. Up to the "?parameter" the URL is steady, parameter is changing.

I would prefer to have this url shown to the customer as 
http:// appname.domain.com/parameter (best solution) or 
http:// appname.domain.com/object?parameter

The combination of redirect and rewrite is too much for my knowledge
The rules I tried didn't work and now I have the hope to get some help from guys with better knowledge than mine...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First create a new website in IIS. Then configure as follows.

1. Inside the website create a folder called "parameter"
2. Select the "parameter" folder and set the redirect as show in the picture 2

[image: New folder in website]

[image: Redirection settings]